# C math function with _BYTE and

Tags: c, ida

I used IDA to decompile a function a program and i don`t know what exactly this code work.

```
flag[i] ^= *((_BYTE *)&v2 + (signed int)i % 4);
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be used for xor-"decrypting" (or encrypting, the operation is symmetric) a buffer with a 4-byte key. See the following code, which might be a bit better readable, than the decompiler output

```
char flag[SIZE];
char key[4];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    flag[i] = flag[i] ^ key[i%4];
}
```

So if your data is "ZGUIHUOHJIOJOPIJMXAR" and your key is "akey", then the snippet basically does

```
  ZGUIHUOHJIOJOPIJMXA
^ akeyakeyakeyakeyake
=====================
  yourplaintextresult (<- not really the result here, but you get the idea)
```

Comment: thank you for support <3 I found the solution last night and have one note. The machine read reverse when you using this. Ex: <br/>                                       <pre>                                                     
   int x = 12578329; // 0xBFEE19
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
  unsigned char byte = *((unsigned char *)&x + i);
  printf("Byte %d = %u\n", i, (unsigned)byte);
}<code>

Answer (score 2):

```
(_BYTE *)&v2
```

This says the address of `v2` should be an address to a variable of type byte

```
(signed int)i % 4
```

This says the remainder of integer `i` divided by 4 (i is probably a loop counter)

```
(_BYTE *)&v2 + (signed int)i % 4
```

This says address that `v2` points to it, should be incremented by (i % 4).

```
*((_BYTE *)&v2 + (signed int)i % 4)
```

This is to dereference the content in memory at position `(v2 + i%4)`

```
flag[i] ^= *((_BYTE *)&v2 + (signed int)i % 4);
```

This says the `i th` element of `flag` array should be XOR-ed with the result of the content in memory at the position of `(v2 + i%4)`